# Connection failure when deploy a Chainlink node with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, blockchain

When I tried to deploy a Chainlink node in the test server (VPS) with Docker, there is a connection failure. I ran PostgreSQL in local (without Docker). IP is 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use --network=host in your run command.